# Recursively list classes/files which are packaged (jar'd) in a maven repository?

Tags: class, maven, jar, repository

Is there a utility or maven command which will list all classes in a repository, recursively?  It could be written crudely with a simple recursive shell script and using "jar -tf", however, I'm assuming this might already be done in a more elegant way, either in maven itself, or externally in some other tool

Answer (score 0):

No such a tool exists for the command line. However, this eclipse [m2eclipse](http://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/repository-sect-repo-view.html) plugin would let you browse into any maven repository. Specifically, for the maven central repository there is a [REST API](http://search.maven.org/#api) that lets you retrieve information from it. Anyway your script approach might be less problematic.

Answer (score 0):

There actually exists a command line tool, which works pretty well: https://code.google.com/p/rjar (it also has an UI option)